# Using transform function on pandas dataframe that returns new value to each row of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I would like to apply a function to each row of a dataframe I have. A snippet of the dataframe is such:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math


data = {'EVENT_ID': [112335580,112335580,112335580,112335580,112335580,112335580,112335580,112335580, 112335582,
                     112335582,112335582,112335582,112335582,112335582,112335582,112335582,112335582,112335582,
                     112335582,112335582,112335582],

 'SELECTION_ID': [6356576,2554439,2503211,6297034,4233251,2522967,5284417,7660920,8112876,7546023,8175276,8145908,
                  8175274,7300754,8065540,8175275,8106158,8086265,2291406,8065533,8125015],

 'BSP': [5.080818565,6.651493872,6.374683435,24.69510797,7.776082305,11.73219964,270.0383021,4,8.294425408,335.3223613,
         14.06040142,2.423340019,126.7205863,70.53780982,21.3328554,225.2711962,92.25113066,193.0151362,3.775394142,
         95.3786641,17.86333041],

  'WIN_LOSE':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['EVENT_ID', 'SELECTION_ID', 'BSP','WIN_LOSE'])

df = df.sort_values(["EVENT_ID","BSP"])
df.set_index(['EVENT_ID', 'SELECTION_ID'], inplace=True)

df['Win_Percentage'] = 1/df['BSP']

df['Lose_Percentage'] = 1 - df['Win_Percentage']
```

I would like to apply the following function to the column `Lose_Percentage`:

```
def test(df):

    x_list = df.values

    y_list = []

    for x in x_list:
        y = math.sin(x/1000)*2000

    return y
```

To do this I use the transform function like such:

```
df['Fit'] = df.groupby(level=0)['Lose_Percentage'].transform(test)
```

The problem is it returns the same value for each row for the `df['Fit']` column. I would like it to return the value taken from that row on  `df['Lose_Percentage']` column and add this to the new  `df['Fit']` column.

If this is done correctly the `df['Fit']` column would contain values for index `112335580`:

```
 [1.499999859375004, 1.6063624685814168, 1.6862587304992693, 1.6993154622916136, 1.742800855666326, 1.8295287282081318, 1.9190120053704878, 1.992593313611782]
```

I have tried to adapt the function like such:

```
def test(df):

    x_list = df.values

    y_list = []

    for x in x_list:
        y = math.sin(x/1000)*2000

        y_list.append(y)

    for fit in y_list:

        return fit
```

But this returns just the same as the previous attempt. I also tried changing the indentation of the return command but this did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, what you want is as simple as

```
df['Fit'] = np.sin(df['Lose_Percentage'] / 1000) * 2000
```

Comment: Ah... pandas is beautifully simple.